# jquery fileupload Basic plugin and deleteing files

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm implement this basic plugin https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin.
and it uploads file.

However for the life of me, I can't add any delete functionailty.
I have looked through the full plugin and googled and looked at other people implementations and am stumpted.

Has anyone managed this?
It would be great for the basic plugin page above to add this as a "How To"

Cheers for any help

Comment: You would just add this functionality separately would you not? A list of files in the upload directory and then just unlinking them if the user chooses to delete them (either through ajax or just "post"ing a form?

Comment: I got the impression this is what the, at least full, plugin provides out of the box...? The full setup at https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup certaining gives this impression...? cheers

Answer (score 1):

Check your webhost hasn't disabled the DELETE method.